# JavaScript function is always returning true where it should be false

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript function is always returning true whatever I write. The problem given wants me to validate that:

1. space at beginning or at end are Not allowed.
2. every character in the field must be a letter or a space (at most 1 space!) to seperate the words in the field (it's about palindrome words, i already wrote its function estPalindrome(word)).
3. the button "chercher" must be enabled once 1 word is valid.

I have also tried to replace `phrase` and `len` inside and outside the function. The results are terrible:

Inside it only alerts "true" when I blur out with empty field
outside it alerts "true" every time, whatever I write.

Note: I am NOT allowed to change anything in HTML code.

```js
var phrase = document.getElementById('phrase').value;
var len = phrase.length;

function estPhrase() {
  var verify = true;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let ch = phrase.charAt(i);
    let isLetter = (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || ch == ' ';
    
    if (!isLetter || (ch == ' ' && phrase.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') || phrase.charAt(0) == ' ' || phrase.charAt(len - 1) == ' ')

      verify = false;
  }

  if (len > 0)
    butt.removeAttribute('disabled');

  var words = new Array();

  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j++) {
    ch = phrase.charAt(i);
    words[j] = "";

    while (ch != ' ') {
      words[j] += ch;
      i++;
    }

    if (estPalindrome(words[j]) == true)
      count++;
  }

  console.log(verify);
}
```

```html
<div> Phrase: <input type="text" id="phrase" onblur="estPhrase()" size="50" /></div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please don't write in text-code here. Use real words and complete sentences (properly capitalized).

Comment: Note that I've converted your alert to a console log. Alerts will drive you (and us) mad.

Comment: you need to move the definitions of `phrase` and `len` *inside* the function. As it is, your function is still using the (empty) value from when the page first loaded.

Comment: This is a good time to use the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement. Add it to the first line of your function and it will act as a breakpoint when running in the browser with dev tools open. This way you can step through your function and see what happens.

Comment: @idk how to use debugger in visual studio tbh, i will try to check youtube for that. thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the html can't be changed and the function `estPhrase()` is called directly from the `<input>` element, then the `phrase` and `len` variables should be moved into the function body.

It was quite hard to refactor and debug your current code based on your current requirements. Certain segments of code were in need of simplification. Whilst I would **not** normally do this, it was just easier to re-write the majority of the function. I know this may not be desirable but doing so may introduce you to new techniques and Javascript functions whilst also improving code readability at the same time.

Not knowing the inner workings of your `estPalindrome()` function, for testing purposes I have return `true` in all cases. Returning `false` would only prevent the `counter` from incrementing.

One thing of note is what 'should' happen if `verify` becomes `false`. Should the `verify` flag be tested prior to splitting the phrase into individual words? If so, then it would abort the remainder of the function and not cause an error in your `estPalindrone()` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div> Phrase: <input type="text" id="phrase" onblur="estPhrase()" size="50"/></div>

        <button id="chercher" disabled>Chercher Button</button>
    </body>

    <script>
        function estPhrase() {
            let phrase = document.getElementById('phrase').value;
            let chercher = document.getElementById('chercher');
            let verify = true;

            // Check phrase does not contain a leading or trailing edge space.
            if (phrase.length !== phrase.trim().length) {
                verify = false;
            }

            // Check phrase does not contain more than one sequential space.
            if (phrase.includes('  ')) {
                verify = false;
            }

            // Check phrase only contains valid characters (a-z, A-Z, space).
            if (/[^a-zA-Z ]/.test(phrase)) {
                verify = false;
            }

            // Bail early on failure. It could also be performed within the above 'if' statements.
            // if (verify === false) {
            //     return;
            // }

            // Now the phrase has been validated, splitting the phrase
            // into words for individual consumption should be error free.
            let words = phrase.split(' ');
            let count = 0;

            // Pass the words one by one into the 'estPalindrone' function.
            for (let word in words) {
                if (estPalindrome(word) === true) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            // Disable button if count is 0.
            if (count === 0) {
                chercher.setAttribute('disabled', '');
            } else {
                chercher.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }

            // Testing.
            console.log('Phrase: ' + phrase);
            console.log('Verify: ' + verify);
            console.log('Words: ' + words);
            console.log('Count: ' + count);
        }

        function estPalindrome(word) {
            // Do stuff with word...
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: woowww i even saw new things in your code optimized to a level i dont know! i totally forgot the split of a string, that could have finished my code since saturday! well, guess i can say thank you! but, the '.disabled = true or false' never worked for me, i had to use removeAttribute for that, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: That's great to hear. Regarding `chercher.disabled` not working, I have updated the answer to reflect both states using `attributes` instead, just in case the word count falls back down to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Modified a little and found it is working fine. [working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-cerf-fiypn0?file=/src/index.js)

```
let phrase = 'abcd  lpp';
// let phrase = ' abcdlpp';
// let phrase = 'abcdlpp ';
// let phrase = 'abc,dlpp';

let len = phrase.length;

function estPhrase() {
  let verify = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let ch = phrase.charAt(i);
    let isLetter = (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || ch === ' ';
    
    if (!isLetter || (ch === ' ' && phrase.charAt(i + 1) === ' ') || phrase.charAt(0) === ' ' || phrase.charAt(len - 1) === ' ')
      verify = false;
  }

  console.log(verify);
}

estPhrase(phrase)
```

Comment: ok thanks for help consideration. it turned out that it's the 'phrase' and len that aren't working, all the logic i worked on is 100% correct, even the == or === doesn't matter. the mistake is the main variables connected to input field of html. i am working on solving it